# React infity loop on function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

i've a (certainly) stupid problem.

my function getDataTbable is called in infinity loop I don't understand why... So the request is infinitive called.

```
    export const TableResearch = ({setSelectedSuggestion,setImages}) => {
const [research, setResearch] = useState('');
const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState ([]);
const [table, setTable]= useState ([]);


const getDataTable = async () => {
  const {data} = await jsonbin.get('/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474');
  setTable(data);
  console.log(table)
};
getDataTable();
```

Comment: Ciao, but you want to call `getDataTable();` just one time at component mounting correct?

Comment: Yes and BARNOWL fix my problem in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The component re-renders every time you change it's state (`setTable`).

You should use `useEffect` to only execute your function the first time it renders.

Also you might encounter this warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

if the async call finishes after component has unmounted. To account for that, write `useEffect` like this:

```
// outside component
const getDataTable = async () => {
    const { data } = await jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474");
    
    return data;
};

useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    getDataTable()
        .then(data => {
            if (!mounted) return;
            setTable(data);
        });

    return () => {
        mounted = false;
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `TableResearch` function is called multiple times (every time this component is rendered). If you want to run a function only when the component is mounted, you'll have to use `useEffect`. Here is an example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const {data} = await jsonbin.get('/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474');
  setTable(data);
}, []);
```

The second parameter `[]` passed to `useEffect` is important. It makes the function run only once.

You can learn more about `useEffect` from [HERE](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getDataTable = async () => {
    const { data } = await jsonbin.get("/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474");
    setTable(data);
    console.log(table);
  };

  getDataTable();
}, []); // [] makes it runs once
```

Comment: I tried it the same before and throw React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency but now it's fix i think i missed something ! thanks

Comment: @Jildo can you mark as answer if this helped you ?\

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `getDataTable();` is being executed everytime the view is rendered, including when the data is returned.

Try wrapping `getDataTable()` like this:

```
if (!table.length) {
  getDataTable()
}
```

But you will need to handle the case for if the requests returns no results, in which case it will still run infinitely:

```
const [table, setTable]= useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading]= useState();

const getDataTable = async () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const {data} = await jsonbin.get('/b/5f3d58e44d93991036184474');
  setTable(data);
  setLoading(false);
};

if (typeof loading === 'undefined' && !table.length) {
  getDataTable();
}
```